# Crofton formula in higher dimension

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, geometric-measure-theory

In the plane, the [Crofton formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula) states that for a rectifiable plane curve $\gamma$, we have

$\int |line \cap \gamma| d\Omega_1=2\times length(\gamma)$

where $d\Omega_1$ is the translation/rotation-invariant measure on the space of all (undirected) lines.

The proof of this is to use addivity, break into line segements, and conclude that the integral is always a constant multiple of the curve length, and therefore we can just do the computation using $\gamma$ as the unit circle to figure out the constant.

Now, this logic carries over in higher dimension. Namely, suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then

$\int |plane \cap \gamma| d\Omega_2 \propto length(\gamma)$

However, how can the constant of proportionality be determined? What would be the "easiest" choice of $\gamma$?

**Remark:** I have seen $\mathbb{R}^3$ versions where $S$ is a surface, and the same logic gives $\int |line \cap S| d\Omega_1 \propto surfacearea(S)$ and the constant of proportionality is easily determined using $S$ being the hollow unit sphere. But changing to curve and plane is suddenly much more difficult...

Comment: The easiest choice will almost certainly be either a line segment or a circle - have you tried the computation for either?

Comment: It might be possible to use an infinite line too - the limit of $\text{len}^{-1} \cdot \int \text{blah}$ might be easier to compute than the integral over a finite segment.

Comment: Based off your suggestion, I used a line segment from $z=1$ to $z=-1$ and it appears to me that the constant should be $\pi$, but I am not sure. Is the measure $d\Omega_2$ given by $\sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi$ ? (where $\theta$ is angle form z-axis and $\phi$ is azimuth angle)

Comment: That seems like the natural generalization to me - check that it's invariant under rigid motions if you're worried.